# Firebird SQL JOIN query multiple FDBs

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

An application we currently use stores its info in multiple firebird database files.

`UserManagement.FDB` contains table `tab_Users` with fields `UserID, Name, Age, etc..`
`components.FDB` contains table `tab_components` with fields `Component_name, User_ID_Owner, etc..`

If a component is owned by a user, their `UserID` is displayed in the `User_ID_Owner` column of the components table.

The `User_ID_Owner` alone means nothing, so I need to generate a query that returns `Component_name, Name` to show the actual name of the person who owns each component.

If I manually copy either table to the other database I can achive it with a JOIN, but I have no idea how i can do this when they are in two seperate fdb's.

Any help would be fantastic!

---

## Update...

@Ed Mendez, Thanks for your Reply! I have made several efforts to make the query work with no success. The exact code i am using is below.

I have been using razorSQL to access the database. Can i run this query directly from there?

```
DECLARE VARIABLE ID INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE NAME VARCHAR (220);
DECLARE VARIABLE NAME_LONG VARCHAR (256);
DECLARE VARIABLE DIRPRJ VARCHAR(520);

EXECUTE STATEMENT 'SELECT ID, NAME, NAME_LONG FROM USERS'

    ON EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE 'localhost:UserManagement.FDB'
    AS USER 'SYSDBA' PASSWORD 'masterkey'
    INTO :ID,
         :NAME,
         :NAME_LONG
DO
BEGIN
  SELECT DIRPRJ
  FROM COMPONENTS
  WHERE USERID_LOCKED = :ID
  INTO :DIRPRJ;
  SUSPEND;
END
```

Comment: maybe interesting: [Can I do multi-database or cross-database queries with Firebird?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq16/).

Answer (score 0):

I would put the following code into a Stored Procedure or inside an Execute Block...

and run it while connected to components.FDB.

```
DECLARE VARIABLE USERID INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE NAME VARCHAR (10);
DECLARE VARIABLE AGE INTEGER;
DECLARE VARIABLE COMPONENT_NAME VARCHAR(10);

EXECUTE STATEMENT 'SELECT USERID,
       NAME,
       AGE
FROM TAB_USERS'
    ON EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE 'localhost:UserManagement.FDB'
    AS USER 'SYSDBA'
       PASSWORD 'masterkey'
    INTO :USERID,
         :NAME,
         :AGE
DO
BEGIN
  SELECT COMPONENT_NAME
  FROM TAB_COMPONENTS
  WHERE USER_ID_OWNER = :USERID
  INTO :COMPONENT_NAME;
  SUSPEND;
END
```